# Set variable value if jQuery AJAX request is error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working on a form that has 4 different ajax request and I want to check if all 4 are successful. If they all are successful I want to switch step.

**Im trying something like this:** 
If i get error on one of the request i want to change the "ss" variable to false.

```
var ss;

ss = true;

if (ss === true) {
this.owner.switchStep(3);
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: JSON.stringify(estate),
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(xhr, thrownError, code) {
        return ss = false;
    },
    complete: function() {}
});


$.ajax({
        ...
        error: function(xhr, thrownError, code) {
            return ss = false;
        },
        ...
    });

$.ajax({
            ...
            error: function(xhr, thrownError, code) {
                return ss = false;
            },
            ...
        });

$.ajax({
            ...
            error: function(xhr, thrownError, code) {
                return ss = false;
            },
            ...
        });
```

Comment: js promise will be better to do this. You can use when...then... in jQuery

Comment: While turning async off solves the problem i think that .when() is a better option but I'm not sure how the syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

Chain your requests or put them synchronous (setting is `async: false`).

Btw are you sure to need 4 ajax requests ?

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem, but I'm trying to get a .when() function working. Trying to figure out the syntax.

Comment: You can also take a look at "real" promises, since jQuery uses deferred which are not, technically speaking, promises. Promises : https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises, Defered : https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/